# Bootstrap input-append does not work on fluid grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input

I am trying to use `input-append` for the search input inside fluid row but unfortunately it does not seem to work correctly as it does not scale to full width of container.

Here is my example piece of code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">


    <div class="input-append">
    <input class="span12" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
    <button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But the input does not scale full width of `span12`. Does anyone know why this is happening or what am I missing?

Comment: Have we answered your question?

Comment: Give me a moment, I am still checking that on my layout. thank you.

Comment: If you have any more questions let me know

Comment: Hi @RaphaelRafatpanah I am trying it in this layout and it does not seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/Trgr6/

Comment: Okay, here:  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/Trgr6/2/  You took out the 95% width rule for some reason, but I added it back in.  Now since it is a span9, it is not going to be 100% width but it will fill up all the space until the span3 starts.  Does this help?

Comment: If you want the "span3" div to be on a separate line and have the search field fill up the entire row, we can do that too. But I have a feeling you don't want to do that since you, yourself put a span9 and span3.

Comment: But if you put the span9 and span3 for strictly structural reasons to "make it work" then let me know and Ill show you how to get around that.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Yes it must be span9 and span3 for now, I am just trying to figure out the way it works. It is going to be a search bar with some options inside and the search. So, how can we make it work? Thank you very much!

Comment: So you would have to do this:  Add a row like you normally do. Do a span9 like you did with an offset of 3.  Then do another row with an offset of 9 and a span of 3.  If you don't know what an offset is, don't worry, it is just an additional class!  Look here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html for more information on offsets.  It explains them nicely.  Please thank me with a check mark!

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Ufff sounds like insane to me, can you show a working example?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I cant belive there is no simple way to fill this black area http://jsfiddle.net/Trgr6/3/

Comment: First, give me credit for the question, since I've clearly answered your original issue.  Then, I'll do a chat with you since comments aren't the best place for this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24404/discussion-between-alex-and-raphael-rafatpanah)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/SXcV3/

```
#appendedInputButton {
    width:100%;
}
```

I also recommend you use the span12 class for the div that holds the input, and not on the input itself.

Update: since bootstrap adds some padding to their buttons for aesthetic reasons, I made the input button width 95% which looks better with no horizontal scroll bar.

Updated jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/SXcV3/1/

Answer (score 1):

for fixed width on the button you can use a different technique

```
.controls { 
    position: relative; 
}

.input-append{
    width: 100%;
}

.input-append input[type="text"]{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto !important;
    margin-right: 42px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.input-append button{
    width: 42px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}

.input-append input[type="text"],
.input-append button{
    height: 42px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: padding-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: padding-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: padding-box;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is unnecessary `.row-fluid` and `.span12` div. Correct markup is

```
<div class="container">


    <div class="input-append">
    <input class="span12" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
    <button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwScz/)

Comment: Without row-fluid my inner columns wont float correct as said on documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to solve the fluidity problems in Bootstrap by employing the border-box box-sizing model. Something like this recently worked for me:

```
.input-append{
    width: 100%;
}

.input-append input[type="text"]{
    width: 90% !important;
}

.input-append button{
    width: 10%;
}

.input-append input[type="text"],
.input-append button{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Obviously you'll want to put this all within the scope of your form, but you get the idea.

Comment: This works a treat but you also need to increase the height on the input to 28px to counter for the padding being applied using border-box. :)